# gdserver cross compilation failed => error: no termcap library found

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, gdbserver

I'm experiencing a frustrating error trying to cross-compile gdbserver for arm. I've downloaded and crosscompiled termcap with this command

```
export CC="/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
export CXX="/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++"
export AR="/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-ar"
CONFOPTS+="--target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --enable-static"
./configure ${CONFOPTS} 
make &&

make DESTDIR=~/gdb-7.6/toInst install
```

Being such crosscompilation successful since I wasn't prompted any error, I got the libtermcap.a which is arm, as you can see below, and located on ~/termcap/

```
:$ file *.o
termcap.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
tparam.o:  ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
version.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), not strippe
```

However, if I try to do the same for cross-compiling gdbserver for arm, with the same options and calling the cross compiled lib

```
export CC="/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
export CXX="/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++"
export AR="/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-ar"

CONFOPTS+="--target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-static --with-termcap=~/termcap/libtermcap.a"
./configure ${CONFOPTS} $@
make &&

make DESTDIR=~/gdb-7.6/toInst install
```

I get this

```
checking for library containing waddstr... no
configure: WARNING: no enhanced curses library found; disabling TUI
checking for library containing tgetent... no
configure: error: no termcap library found
make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `~/gdb-7.6'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have found several sites on the internet suggesting installing the library libncurses5-dev, but have I already installed!

```
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 67 not upgraded.
```

SO, I don't know what can I do to crosscompile gdbserver, please help!

Thanks in advance!!

regards

Comment: [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) has options to build a `gdbserver` when generating a cross compiler.  You can start with on of the sample configurations and tweak it.  Most likely you have to tell the `gdb` configure where to locate the *ARM* termcaps if you want to do it manually like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a work-around to cross-compile gbd, since I was only interested in crosscompiling the gdbserver, I went to that folder(gdb/gdebserver0 and using the cofigure there located, with my cross-compiling options, I hadn't got any trouble and now I get the gbd server for arm.

I hope this can help aother one with my same issue.

regards

Answer (score 1):

Here,    I am suggesting the automated solution for the configure:    configure error no termcap library found while compiling crosstool-ng.    It is perfectly working in latest Fedora release

```
1.Download the termcap-1.3.1.tar.gz from the gnu site    
2.Uncompress the source File >tar -xvf termcap-1.3.1.tar.gz    
3.>cd termcap     4>./configure  /*Configure the Library*/    
5.>make    /*user  */    
6.>su    /* change to root */    
7.then > make install
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case it took less then 5 minutes to download, cross-build termcap and pass its location to the GDB configure script via `LDFLAGS=-Lpath`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a FC3 but even installing libncurses-devel it didn't work. The solution for me was installing readline-devel